# Calling locally hosted Parse Server Cloud Code with Javascript

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-server

I have Parse-Server hosted locally and I have the Parse-Server-Example test working.  I'm able to call the example cloud code function using the test code (/test) that Parse-Server-Example uses.  When I replace the main.js file with my legacy cloud code (from Parse.com hosted server), I can't seem to figure out how to call it.  The Parse-Server-Example /test call to my replaced cloud code works just fine.  I just can't seem to call the cloud code from my own javascript.  Here's my client side javascript code:

```
function helloMyParse(){
Parse.initialize("myAppId", "myMastKey");
Parse.serverURL = 'http://192.168.1.239:1337/parse';
Parse.Cloud.run('hello', 
    { 
    XXXXXXX
    }, {
        success: function(results) {
```

Any ideas greatly appreciated!

Above code throws the following error:

```
  Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)   http://192.168.1.239:1337/parse/1/functions/hello
```

Comment: u could try grep on *js for that "/1" in the path. Dont think u should have the /1 any longer... but i cant tell where the request for that path is coming from.

Comment: Yeah.  Odd.  the "/1/functions/"  in the path is being generated by Parse-Server. It's definitely not in my code.

Comment: may be worth looking at the CC-router in a debugger... parse-server/routers/cloudcoderouter.js

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the line Parse.cloud = ...

Also, this is Parse.Cloud.run with a capital C

Comment: Using a capital "C" in Parse.Cloud.run appear to be working.  See edits above.

Comment: Also, I tried removing the Parse.cloud = ...    and, I got the same 404 error as described above.  I believe from everything I've read that I really need the Parse.cloud = ....    statement.  That tells parse where my cloud code lives.

Comment: No you don't need that, you need to specify the cloud module when you initialize ParseServer, but not on the client

Comment: Makes sense.  I note that the server side "index.js" config file in the parse-server-example directory does list the location of the Cloud Code.  ('/cloud/main.js').  So, I removed the above "Parse.cloud =" line.  I still get the same 404 error

Comment: To clarify for posterity, setting `Parse.cloud = <PATH>;` is for when you are setting up your parse-server. This line tells parse-server which file contains your cloud code. So when someone makes an http request to `<YOUR_PARSE_SERVER>/functions/functionName`, it knows which file on the server to look for `Parse.Cloud.define("functionName" ...);`  This is *not* used when a javascript *client* is trying to call a cloud code function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the /1 in your url.  You also shouldn't need:

`Parse.cloud = './cloud/main.js';`  though it probably isn't causing any harm.

How are you running the above code?  Is it in its own file?  Where?

Let's see if we can start here.  Open a command line and try this:

```
curl -X POST \
  -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ### your're app id here ####" \
  -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
  -d '{"foo":"bar"}' \
  http://192.168.1.239:1337/parse/functions/hello
```

Comment: OK.  So, running this curl command runs successfully.  It calls the 'hello' Cloud Code function as prescribed.

Comment: My HTML code links, calls, and runs a very large javascript file.  That javascript code hits my Parse-Server database on another physical machine, and successfully accesses and saves data, etc.  That javascript code also calls the Parse-Server Cloud code which throws the 404 error.

Comment: interestingly, and this is probably critical, the "/1" is not in my code, but is only displayed on the Error Console as part of the error thrown.  No idea where that is coming from.

Comment: So, the Parse.Cloud.run line is throwing the 404 error, and the explanation is "Cannot GET /parse/1/functions/hello".

Comment: So you're likely using the wrong version of the parse sdk in your javascript.  it is probably a version before it accounted for a self hosted parse-server. That is almost certainly where the /1 is coming . parse sdk lib?

Answer (score 0):

My bad.  I was using an old version of Parse SDK. The parsecdn is not the latest.  Cloud code requires the latest SDK.  The new SDK knows where Cloud Code lives.  Problem solved

```
    <!--  Replaced 09-23-16     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-latest.js"></script> -->

    <!--  New CDN  09-24-16-->    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://npmcdn.com/parse@1.9.1/dist/parse.min.js"></script>
```